# Why do speakers usually omit 'in total'?

Tags: grammatical-number

If there are six apples in total, if 'in total' is omitted, it can mislead listeners. For example, if I just say there are six apples, listeners can think there are seven or more apples in total. Is it related to pragmatics or something?

Comment: “in total” is for when you’re adding subgroups. If I have three apples in one hand and three in the other, I have six apples in total. And very big hands.

Comment: But speakers usually omit 'in total' although they're adding subgroups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say "there are six apples", with no other context people will think there are six.

If you ask someone how many apples there are and there are 7, it would be ridiculous to say "there are six apples (and one more)"

On the other hand if some one says "I need six apples to make a pie, do we have six apples in the cupboard?"  You check and there are seven.  It would be reasonable to say "Yes" because you know that it is possible to make a pie.

Nothing here is specific to English. The same is true in every language.

There are some situations in which you need to be more specific. "In total" is not the right phrase, instead you should use one of "exactly", "at least", "more than" or "no more than"  You probably wouldn't need to say

> There are exactly six apples in the cupboard.

But if students are not allowed to pick three or five GCSE options, a teacher could say:

> Students should pick exactly four GCSE options.

To emphasise the requirement to be exact.